# ASP.NET MVC C# - How to reference function outside the Views folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Problems(scenarios):

1. I have a function in my Views folder, it is called "EncodeID".
2. Upon searching that function, it is located outside that Views folder. 
   Project > Modules > "public static string EncodeID(dynamic ID)"
3. Issue here, there's a red curly line in the EncodeID function saying when I hover it "The name EncodeID does not exist in the current context".

Questions:

1. How can I reference that function to my Views file?
2. How can I copy the error instantly in VS studio? because I'm just manually typing it?

Code in my Views folder:

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Shoutbox", new{@page = 1, @id = EncodeID(Session("EmployeeID"))})">View My Posts</a></li>
```

Code in my Modules folder > Modfunction.cs.

```
   public static string EncodeID(dynamic ID)
    {
        byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((char[])ID);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
    }
```

Comment: Add a `@using yourAssemby` to the view, or use `@id = yourAssembly.EncodeID(...)`

Comment: Function can not exist outside of a class. And `EncodeID` function is a static function so all you need to do is to use `ClassName.EncodeID` to use that function in your view..

Comment: Thank you guys. I love you all! <3 Just a noobie. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full namespace of the function. Eg: `MyProject.Modules.Modfunction.EncodeID`

Comment: Thank you guys. I love you all! <3 Just a noobie. :)